# DOM .value attribute not working - returning blank string

Tags: javascript, html

For whatever reason, the .value attribute on the input boxes is not returning the values entered. When running it through the Number(), it returns 0, and without it returns a blank string. I have no idea why, I looked at at least a dozen various sites for answers but I can't find an answer. This is really a last-ditch effort to get this thing to work. Thanks in advance, and I hope it's not a dumb syntax thing. Pesky section of code below.

```
<div>
      <label for="angleAInput">A=</label>
      <input id="angleAInput" type="number" placeholder="mesure en degrés"><br>
      <label for="sideAInput">a=</label>
      <input id="sideAInput" type="number" placeholder="mesure en unités de longueur"><br>
      <label for="sideBInput">b=</label>
      <input id="sideBInput" type="number" placeholder="mesure en unités de longueur">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="go">Triangle ou non?</button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="result"></h2>
    <script>
const go = document.querySelector('.go');
const result = document.querySelector('.result');
let A = Number(document.querySelector('#angleAInput').value);
let a = Number(document.querySelector('#sideAInput').value);
let b = Number(document.querySelector('#sideBInput').value);
let bsinA = b * Math.sin(A * Math.PI / 180);

go.addEventListener('click', output);

function output() {
    result.textContent = A;
}
</script>
```

Comment: The "let A = " part is run before any input. The selections belong in the output() function.

Answer (score 1):

Those values are the values of the input on page load, not when the user clicks the button.

Retrieve the values inside the `click` event listener.

```html
<div>
  <label for="angleAInput">A=</label>
  <input id="angleAInput" type="number" placeholder="mesure en degrés"><br>
  <label for="sideAInput">a=</label>
  <input id="sideAInput" type="number" placeholder="mesure en unités de longueur"><br>
  <label for="sideBInput">b=</label>
  <input id="sideBInput" type="number" placeholder="mesure en unités de longueur">
</div>
<div>
  <button class="go">Triangle ou non?</button>
</div>
<h2 class="result"></h2>
<script>
  const go = document.querySelector('.go');
  const result = document.querySelector('.result');

  go.addEventListener('click', output);

  function output() {
    let A = Number(document.querySelector('#angleAInput').value);
    let a = Number(document.querySelector('#sideAInput').value);
    let b = Number(document.querySelector('#sideBInput').value);
    let bsinA = b * Math.sin(A * Math.PI / 180);
    result.textContent = A;
  }
</script>
```